# if log n^2 is big theta of log n , is (logn)^2 also big theta of logn?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

`log n^2` is equivalent to `2logn` which grows at the same rate as `logn`, as I disregard the factors and constants. but if I was to square the whole term so that I end up with `(logn)^2` is it also big theta of `logn`?

Comment: can you explain to me why? I just plotted the graph of log(n) vs (log(n))^2 and it seems to be growing at a higher rate?

Comment: [link]https://graphsketch.com/render.php?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=log(x)&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=(log(x))%5E2&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-17&x_max=100&y_min=-10.5&y_max=10.5&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525

Comment: log(n)^2 grows faster, not slower than log(n).

Comment: This math answer may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1271175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If f is any unbounded function then f(n)^2 is not O(f).

Because f(n)^2 = O(f) means there's a c and N such that n > N implies f(n)^2 <= cf(n). Which implies f(n) <= c, and so f is bounded.

log(n) is unbounded, so log(n)^2 is not O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Think this way: let `N=log(n)`. Then `f1(N)=N^2` where `f2(N)=N`, obviously,
`N=o(N^2)!=theta(N^2)`, i.e., `log(n)=o((log(n))^2)!=theta((log(n))^2)`.

Also, `lim {n->inf} f2(n) / f1(n) = lim {n->inf} 1 / log(n) = 0`, by definition of small `o` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) it implies `f2(n)=o(f1(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

log (n^2) = 2 log(n) 
and as you know x^2 is not in thetha(x).